# Efficient algorithm to group points in clusters by distance between every two points

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am looking for an efficient algorithm for the following problem:

Given a set of points in 2D space, where each point is defined by its X and Y coordinates. Required to split this set of points into a set of clusters so that if distance between two arbitrary points is less then some threshold, these points must belong to the same cluster:

[image: sample clusters]

In other words, such cluster is a set of points which are 'close enough' to each other.

The naive algorithm may look like this:

1. Let **R** be a resulting list of clusters, initially empty
2. Let **P** be a list of points, initially contains all points
3. Pick random point from **P** and create a cluster **C** which contains only this point. Delete this point from **P**
4. For every point **Pi** from **P**
   4a. For every point **Pc** from **C**
   4aa. If **distance(Pi, Pc) < threshold** then add **Pi** to **C** and remove it from **P**
5. If at least one point was added to cluster **C** during the step 4, go to step 4
6. Add cluster **C** to list **R**. if **P** is not empty, go to step 3

However, naive approach is very inefficient. I wonder if there is a better algorithm for this problem?

*P.S. I don't know the number of clusters apriori*

Comment: If you compute a matrix where the [x][y] place is the distance between the point x and the point y. Then, iterate over it so that if the distance is less than the threshold, mark the place with a 1, otherwise a 0. Now we have a graph that we can use either DFS or BFS to find all the clusters. It may not be very efficient, but it reduces it to an easier problem

Comment: Whatever method you choose, make sure you compare the distance squared `(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2` with the threshold squared, to avoid having to calculate square roots.

Comment: And look into storing the points in a space-partitioning tree.

Comment: sounds like a job for [linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis)?

Answer (score 7):

There are some classic algorithms here:

- Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering
- DBSCAN

that you should read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split up the space of points into a grid. This grid would have unit length equal to **threshhold / sqrt(8)**.
2. Iterate though the list of points **P**, adding each point to both the square it occupies and a new cluster. If a point is added to a square which already contains a point, add it to the cluster of the other point(s). I'll call the list of all occupied sqaures **S**.
3. Now take any square from **S** and its cluster **c**. For each adjacent or diagonal  square, combine the cluster of that square with **c** and remove the square from **S**. Repeat the process for all squares just added.
4. Once no more adjacent sqaures can be found, the cluster is finished and can be added to **C**. Repeat step 3 with any remaining squares in **S**. When **S** is empty, you're finished.

Comment: This is not right. A grid can help find candidates for points within a certain distance threshold, but it cannot replace an explicit check: any grid size will either be small enough that two points can be closer than the threshold without being in adjacent/diagonal squares, or big enough that two points can be in adjacent/diagonal squares without being closer than the threshold, or both. (Yours has the former problem.)

Comment: Also, it's not obvious to me that this is faster than the OP's strategy, since the complexity of "combining" two clusters is non-obvious. BFS or DFS over occupied squares probably makes more sense.

Comment: @ruakh It's clearly not optimal, but I think it would be faster than the OP's solution since it doesn't require checking every point against all non-clustered points. I did overlook the first problem however. Thanks for the comments